# Setting custom billing period on Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, subscription, billing, recurring-billing

I'm using stripe to handle subscriptions on a project I'm working on and I wanted to test recurring renewal of subscriptions by reducing the billing period of subscription to few minutes but all the answers that I have found so far are to set a billing period of 1 day or reset the billing cycle from stripe dashboard.

Is there any other way to set billing cycle of 10-15 minutes so I can test recurring payments properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a billing cycle of less than a day on a Stripe Subscription.  The best option is usually to [update the Subscription's `billing_cycle_anchor`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-billing_cycle_anchor) which will cause [the Customer to be invoiced immediately](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#changing).

Answer (score 0):

Stripe has a feature called [Test Clocks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/testing/test-clocks) that allows to move subscriptions forward in time. So you could create a subscription with a test clock, then advance the clock by one month to see exactly what happens.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).